# Most efficient way to compare lists Python

Tags: python, arrays, compare

How can I compare lists to one another. I am looking to compare the first - fourth digit of two lists.
I'm aware of being able to do
`if list[1] == list[1]:` but id assume there is a more efficient way to get it done. Thank you. I don't want to compare the lists overall, just x part of one list to x part of another

````
import random
import replit
import numpy
import time
number = 0
answer = 0
guesses = 0
x = 0
useranswer = []
generated = []
for i in range (0,4):
  num = random.randrange(1,9)
  generated.append(num)
replit.clear()
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------\nWelcome to MASTERMIND! you must guess the number that was generated!\n---------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
def useranswer():
  answer = str(input("Select a 4 digit number: "))
  if len(answer) != 4:
    print("Invalid answer type")
    time.sleep(999999999)
    answer = ' '
  else:
    useranswer = list((str(answer)))
  
  
if useranswer == generated:
  print("Good job! You became the MASTERMIND in one turn!")
else: 
  while useranswer != generated:
    useranswer()
    guesses +=1
    if useranswer == generated:
      print("You have become the mastermind in " + guesses + " tries!")
    else:
      c = numpy.intersect1d(useranswer, generated, return_indices=True)[1]
      print("You got " + c + " correct! ")```
````

Comment: Does "first - fourth digit of two lists" mean first four items of the lists?

Comment: Please provide sample input and expected output.  At first glance it seems you're only looking to do something like `if list1[:4] == list2[:4]:`

Comment: yes. comparing the first part of an array to the first part of another.

Comment: I want to display that the first part of a list is equal to another part. but not the second part. For example
list1 = [1,2,6,8]
list2 = [1,4,6,10]

the first and third are equal to eachother

Comment: Based on index, or based on whether or not an item exists on both lists? In other words, would `op([1, 2], [2, 1])` return true or false?

Answer (score 1):

You can always use **list slicing** to *compare the specified range* of items between lists.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8]
b = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a[:3] == b[:3]
```

The above will yield a **True** if they match.

If you want to return the **indexes of common elements between the two lists**, there's a library called Numpy which has powerful features to do such jobs *efficiently*.

```
import numpy
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [0, 4, 6, 2]
_, c, d = numpy.intersect1d(a, b, return_indices=True)
```

This would return the following indexes:

```
print(c)
print(d)
array([0, 1, 3]
array([0, 3, 1])
```

But the answer to your question:

```
import random
import replit
import copy
import numpy
import time
number = 0
answer = 0
guesses = 0
x = 0
useranswer = []
generated = []
for i in range (0,4):
    num = random.randrange(1,9)
    generated.append(num)
replit.clear()
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------\nWelcome to MASTERMIND! you must guess the number that was generated!\n---------------------------------------------------------------------\n")
def useranswer_func():
    answer = str(input("Select a 4 digit number: "))
    if len(answer) != 4:
        print("Invalid answer type")
        time.sleep(9)  # The time provided by you is too much to wait!
        answer = ' '
    else:
        useranswer = list(answer)
        # You need to return values to use them outside the function.
        # Also your generated has int values but useranswer have str. So convert them to int or else they would never compare!
        return [int(i) for i in useranswer] 


if useranswer == generated:
      print("Good job! You became the MASTERMIND in one turn!")
else: 
    while useranswer != generated:
        # The returned values need to be stored in a variable.
        # Never use function name and variable name same. That could cause the error that you posted in the comment!
        useranswer = useranswer_func()
        guesses += 1
        if useranswer == generated:
            print("You have become the mastermind in " + str(guesses) + " tries!")
        else:
            c = []
            temp = copy.deepcopy(generated) # So that the change you make in temp is not reflected in generated variable too.
            for i in range(len(generated)):
                if generated[i] == useranswer[i]:
                    c.append(temp.index(temp[i]))
                temp[i] = None # If your generated has repeated values, the index returned will be different or else it would be always same.

            print("You got " + str(c) + " correct! ")
```

Comment: with this, can i compare to see if only the 1st/4th are equal if 2/3 arent? i am attempting to recreate mastermind using python

Comment: Oh, so you want to compare single elements and not a part of array?

Comment: yes exactly like that. I just didn't know how to describe it.

Comment: So is it fine if we return the indexes of common elements/if they match?

Comment: yes, that way i can print it inside my code

Comment: Hey, i attempted to use the numpy solution, and got the following error.
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 58, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'function' and 'int'`

Comment: I appreciate the help, and I myself am extremely new to python and code as a whole

Comment: Can you share your code? It is difficult to reproduce the above error.

Comment: yes, but i cant post the full code, so i will post it in my original post

Comment: Thank you! appreciate the help.